# Android: ViewBinder - modifying ListView columns larger than Cursor content

Tags: android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView which shows 3 values from an SQLite database (columns 1, 2 & 3). To the right of those values I want to put some ImageButtons. My question is - how do I modify what appears in columns 4 and above?

I have overridden setViewValue() but this only gets called for columns in the Cursor (sort of what I would expect). How can I modify what appears in a particular row for columns 4 and above? Would I override the getView() method somehow? If I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter - does that mean that I should be creating a subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter and then overriding the getView() method?

Comment: you need to implement ViewBinder interface,  no need for extending SCA in any way

Comment: @pskink: ViewBinder only has the setViewValue() method as far as I can tell - and that doesn't appear to let you change values that are not in the Cursor.

Comment: @pskink: The only idea I can think of is to access the parent View whenever setViewValue() is called and then find the Views for columns 4 and above.

Comment: see the first View param of setViewValue,  that's the View you need to map your data to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
  public class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder
  {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue( View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex )
    {
      if( columnIndex == 1 )
      {
        View vParent = (View) view.getParent();

        ImageView ivPlaylist = (ImageView) vParent.findViewById( R.id.ibAddPlaylist );

        if( ivPlaylist != null )
        {  
          ivPlaylist.setImageResource( R.drawable.clipboard30x30purple );
        }
```

Comment: why view.getParent()?, "view" parameter is a View you are looking for

Comment: @pskink: The example I used with ViewBinder showed a list of items with a star next to them. The guy set View.GONE for the state on the View you are referring to and only the star ImageView disappeared, not the entire row. If I use view instead of vParent, it crashes.

Comment: if your Cursor has _id column plus three additional columns: c0, c1 and c2, and when creating SCA you use from = ["c0","c1","c2"] and your latout has three TextViews with ids: tv0,  tv1,  tv2 and to = [tv0,  tv1,  tv2] then setViewValue will be called three times for each row,  each time with different TextView and different columnIndex

Comment: @pskink: Correct, but I want to access the ImageViews iv3, iv4 and iv5 for which there is no column index within the Cursor. These are arbitrary ImageViews that do no directly relate to what is in the Cursor. My solution is working fine - I don't want to access tv0, tv1 and tv2 - I want to access ListView columns outside of the to=[] range.

Comment: just add the ids to "to" array and add fake columns like _id to "from" array ,  or if you think ViewBinder is too complex override bindView,  make sure to call super

Comment: @pskink: Thanks that sounds quite useful.